# Inserting values from a list the tkinter text widget using commas

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a UI that allows to check if the font used in the paragraphs of a Word document is Times New Roman or not. If paragraphs are written using any other font(s), the font name(s) are displayed to the user, via the tkinter (8.6) text widget. The invalid font(s) are stored in a set.

Each invalid font is separated by a comma in the text widget. However, a comma also appears after the last element of the set. This behaviour is not desired.

I would like to know how I can prevent a comma from appearing after the last element.

The code was written using Python (3.10) on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3).

The code is shown below. The code only shows the function used to check the font and not the whole code as it involves buttons and may be too long. Any help is welcomed.

```
# function that checks font
def font_name():
    if var1.get() == 1:
        # access file
        doc = Document(filename)
        # check font for paragraphs
        font = set()  # store all font names
        invalid_fonts = set()  # store unacceptable font
        VALID_FONT = 'Times New Roman'  # state the valid font
        for paragraphs in doc.paragraphs:
            if 'Normal' == paragraphs.style.name:
                for run in paragraphs.runs:
                    # add fonts from each run
                    font.add(run.font.name)
                    # check if fonts are valid
                    if run.font.name != VALID_FONT:
                        invalid_fonts.add(run.font.name)

        # check if all elements in font are VALID_FONT
        if {VALID_FONT} == font:
            output_display.insert("All paragraphs are written in Times New Roman font." + '\n')
            # check if all elements in font are not VALID_FONT
        elif {VALID_FONT} != font:
            output_display.insert('end', "Paragraph written in unrecognised font(s): ")
            for invalid_fonts in invalid_fonts:
                output_display.insert('end', invalid_fonts + ', ')  # add invalid font(s) to text widget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '3']

display = tk.Text(root)
display.insert(tk.END, ','.join(my_list))
display.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That certainly is a valid way to accomplish the task. However, I really need the for loop in my code. So when I using `str.join()` with the for loop (ie, `str.join(my_list)`) I get an output like this:
11,2,3,321,2,3,331,2,3,331,2,3,3. 
The reason I need the for loop is that for my required purpose I do not have a predefined list, so looping through the list and then printing its elements is better.

Comment: @catcher It is better to provide a realistic example of the list you use so that `str.join()` does not work as expected.

Comment: ok I will edit my post. I provided a much simplified version to avoid code that was too long or complicated.

Comment: @catcher I don't see why `str.join()` does not work on `invalid_fonts` as it is just a set of font names.

Comment: when I use: `for invalid_fonts in invalid_fonts: output_display.insert('end', ','.join(invalid_fonts))` the output is as follows: A,r,i,a,lB,a,h,n,s,c,h,r,i,f,tA,b,a,d, 
I have no idea as to why all the letters are separated by commas.

Comment: @catcher You don't need the for loop as in my answer.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense now. So I removed the for loop and then added:
`output_display.insert('end', ', '.join(invalid_fonts))` Appreciate the help.